# OpenGL glColorMaterial doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl

I can not draw a color material. How can I draw color material?
I tried the code below:

```
 glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, material._Ka);
 glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, material._Kd);
 glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, material._Ks);
 // glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION, ...);
 glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, material.Ns);

 //glColor4fv(material._Kd);

 glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE);
 glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR);
 glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT);
 glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS);
```

This results in an error (error 1280) at:

```
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS);
```

Comment: Dont use the deprecated fixed function pipeline! And of course tthe code above is not enough to tell you why it is not working!

Comment: What do I use the new function

Comment: glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS); return 1280 error..

Comment: If you keep asking terrible questions without really sitting down on your lazy bum and reading a bit, you will be question-banned soon.

Comment: Please don't try to destroy your questions. That is not appropriate behaviour.

Comment: And one word of advice: don't delete your downvoted posts. The more you do so, the closer you are to a post-ban. Meaning you won't be able to post on the site any more. If you can, improve them instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you look up [error code 1280](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Error) (0x0500 in hex), you'll notice that it's `GL_INVALID_ENUM`.

Or in other words, an enum value you're using is an inappropriate parameter for `glColorMaterial`.

Looking up [glColorMaterial](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glColorMaterial.xml), it's not all that hard to see that `GL_SHININESS` is not an acceptable value. So there's your problem.

Comment: i deleted glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS); problems no chanage :(

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz's comment might sound harsh, but it's true. Don't try to program in the blind. OpenGL comes with a lot of documentation. Or if you want to pick up modern OpenGL, read this: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ If you encounter an error as the above, try to figure out what that means. The  more you become self-reliant, the better your questions will ultimately be.